# jQuery Datepicker not working on date select

Tags: jquery, date, datepicker

firstly apologize if I'm mislooking on another solutions but I didn't manage get the ways out of this issues. My html, script codes and definition are placed correctly and it's working to display and popup the datepicker calendar, but the problems comes out when to select the date. Here's my code for review if I am missing something.

HTML code

```
<table style="border:none">
                                <tbody><tr>
                                    <td>Date From: &nbsp;</td>
                                    <td><input class="form-control input-sm" id="from" name="from" size="10" required="" type="text"></td>
                                    <td> </td>
                                    <td>Date To: &nbsp;</td>
                                    <td><input class="form-control input-sm" id="to" name="to" size="10" required="" type="text"></td>
                                </tr>
                                </tbody></table>
```

Javascript

```
$("#from").val(moment().format('DD/MM/YYYY'));
$("#to").val(moment().format('DD/MM/YYYY'));
$('#from, #to').datepicker({
  format: 'dd/mm/yyyy'
});
```

Script definition on 'head' section(include all script declaration for clear define on my problems).

```
<script src="/strateq/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/strateq/js/jquery.redirect.js"></script>
    <script src="/strateq/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/strateq/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/strateq/js/moment.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/strateq/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/strateq/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/strateq/js/metisMenu.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/strateq/js/sb-admin-2.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try this..

```
$('#from, #to').datepicker({
    format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
    startDate: moment().format('DD/MM/YYYY'),
    endDate: moment().format('DD/MM/YYYY')
});
```

But this will just cover the initial page load.. If you need to also detect a change event you'll need to look at the [event](http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/events.html#) docs.

```
.on(picker_event, function(e) {
    // `e` here contains the extra attributes
});
```

Untested but give it a whirl..

```
$('#from, #to').datepicker({
    format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
    startDate: moment().format('DD/MM/YYYY'),
    endDate: moment().format('DD/MM/YYYY')
}).on('changeDate', function(e) {
    // do something..
});
```

Comment: I'd tried the first code, but it gets blurred on datepicker box. however, in my html head section on meta tag, I add content-security-policy, I add "unsafe-inline" within script-src which is ingored by CSP itself. does it cause the problems I'm facing now?